# Is There Any Function or Algorithm For [Draw a Feature Surrounds Another Feature]?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, openlayers

I have to use OpenLayers to create a logic that draws two Features.
After the user draws Feature A,
We need logic to draw Feature B that surrounds the Feature A outside.

1. Draw Feature A on a map.
2. After Feature A is drawn, the system must create Feature B that surrounds Feature A.
3. The final result should be the same as Image.

[image: Result what I want]

PRECONDITION

1. Feature can have 3 - 6 angles.
2. The length of each side is unpredictable.
3. The angle of each side is unpredictable.
4. All sides of Feature B must be made from all sides of Feature A with the distance specified by the user.
   How do we solve this problem?

full source code : https://github.com/JeahaOh/OpenLayersStudy/tree/master/Examples/EffectiveRange/CDN

Answer (score 1):

Hey this looks like creating a geometry with a buffer of x (x is defined by the user).

You can use [JSTS](http://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/) to create buffers from a geometry and then map it back to an openlayer geometry.

[OpenLayers example](https://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/jsts.html?q=jsts) that draws geometries with a buffer. This example uses LineString geometries but you can use any geometry.

Looking at your example you probably want sharp edges on your outer geometry so you can use a mitre line join style

```
var bufParams = new jsts.operation.buffer.BufferParameters();
bufParams.setJoinStyle(
   jsts.operation.buffer.BufferParameters.JOIN_MITRE)
var outer = inner.buffer(spacing, bufParams);
```

See [docs for BufferParameters](https://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/doc/api/jsts.operation.buffer.BufferParameters.html) for more options.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s3g1e7am/29/) that shows it.